# After parsing url as json, can't return a specific element from list- only whole list

Tags: python

All,

I wrote the following code:

```
import requests,bs4
res=requests.get('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=551798799')
res.raise_for_status()
wwe=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
print wwe.select('p averageUserRating')
```

If I only do: print wwe.select('p') then the code works, but it prints everything in the list. However when I print what is in the output above, this throws an error saying the selector is unsupported.

I am basically only trying to return the averageUserRating value (which is 4.0).
Thanks for the help!

Comment: That file is JSON, not HTML, so BeautifulSoup wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of that file isn't HTML, which is what BeautifulSoup is designed to read; it's a different data format called [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Thankfully, the `requests` library makes it really easy to parse JSON - if you call `.json()` on a response it parses it into a dictionary. You need to access `averageUserRating`, which is inside the first element of the `results` list, so you can use this to access what you need:

```
>>> data = res.json()
>>> data["results"][0]["averageUserRating"]
4.0
```

To modify your existing code:

```
import requests
res=requests.get('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=551798799')
res.raise_for_status()
wwe=res.json()
print data["results"][0]["averageUserRating"]
```